# Bootstrap - collapse navbar bug when adding a border on hover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I added a border-bottom to my navbar li on hover like the following:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover{
    border-bottom: 4px solid #62c4a4;
}
```

However this causes the navbar-collapse to appear as a tiny box with a scrollbar instead of expanding the list items.

[image]

How can I make sure the navbar-collapse expands normally and the border on hover effect still shows?

code pen http://codepen.io/meek/pen/NNprYb

Comment: Please add a starting point in code (for example a JSFiddle or CodePen) to give your question a proper solution. *Only* an image won't help solving the problem. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Roy added now, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `height` of `.navbar-collapse.collapse.in .navbar-nav` to `auto`, like this:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in .navbar-nav {
  height: auto;
}
```

Because the Bootstrap CSS is setting the `height` to `70px`, the height of the navigation bar. You want to change it (setting it to `auto`) when the menu is active.

Comment: ohh I see what was causing the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with you setting the height to 70px;

```
.navbar-default, .navbar-nav {
//height: 70px;
}
```

When you comment that out you don't get the scrollbar.